# Website and clickable items on iPad/iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, mobile, click

I have been building a website so that it is responsive to tablets such as iPhone and iPad, however I'm having an issue with clickable items.

For instance, I currently have my navigation "position:fixed" so that regardless of how far you scroll down the page it is always there. The problem I am having though is after you click on the dropdown menu and select a section to jump to when I go back to select another section it doesn't work. I have to scroll a little bit to activate the navigation so that I can click on the menu again.

Can anyone help me out please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the touchevent?

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$("put your selector here").bind(event, function(e) {

});
```

Comment: I have that in my code. So I click on the menu button and a list appears, I then click on a link and it skips to that section and hides the list. I try clicking on the menu button again to show the list and nothing...I have to slightly scroll the screen to activate the list button when I press on it... I don't know what is stopping it from working?

Comment: Can you try $(window).trigger("resize"); just to see if triggering the screen size will activate the list again?